# Cannot get correct state of checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zurb-foundation

Something weird is happening. Im using [foundation switch](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/switch.html) as my checkbox.

When I look at my state on the react browser tool, my check state is true. When I console log the state in the handler, it's false. Where is the bug?

**es6:**

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    checked: false
  },
  this._handleChange = this._handleChange.bind(this)
}

_handleChange(){
  this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked });
  console.log(this.state.checked); // becomes the opposite the state!
}
```

**render:**

```
<div className="switch">
  <input className="switch-input" id="exampleSwitch" type="checkbox" onChange={this._handleChange} checked={this.state.checked} name="exampleSwitch">
  <label className="switch-paddle" htmlFor="exampleSwitch">
    <span className="show-for-sr">Download Kittens</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

When clicked, my react console shows it as `true` but in console, it's `false`. The `console.log()` shows the opposite of the state. If the state is `false` then the log shows `true`. Any reason?

Edit for another method:

```
_onSubmit(){
 let checked = this.state.checked;
 $.ajax({
  ...
  data: {"checked": checked },
  ...
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From React [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html):

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value.

So `console.log()` may work in unexpected manner here. To get proper result you probably would like to pass 2nd argument to your `setState()`:

> The second (optional) parameter is a callback function that will be
>   executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered.

```
_handleChange(){
  this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.checked); // output will be as expected
  });  
}
```

Comment: Ahh. Ok. But I need to know if the state is true for false do I can send that with ajax.

Comment: Thanks. In another method with an ajax call, I can safely use `this.state.checked`?

Comment: @Sylar please update your question, I don't know what `another method` you're talking about, how it looks etc. Thanks!

Comment: Ok I have made changes. Never mind. Your answer is all good. Thanks.

Comment: @Sylar yes, it's ok to use it in this way!

Answer (score 0):

**setState()** is not a synchronous action and therefore the API gives you the ability to give it a callback to do something when the **setState()** completes. Example below with code that is not tested. Documentation : [Facebook setState() documentation.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html)

```js
var Component = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
        return ({
          initialState: true
        });
      },
      changeState: function() {
        this.setState({
          initialState: false
        }, function() {
          console.log(this.state.initialState); // this is the callback
        });
      },
      render: function() {
          return ( 
            <button type="button" onClick = {this.changeState}> Test component </button>
          );
  }                                
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```